# How do I remove extra divs added by panels?

Tags: panels

Panels adds additional classes and divs which are unnecessary for my purpose. How can I remove these?

Comment: Same way as all theming, supply your own template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple ways you can tackle this.

One option is to simply create your own panel layouts.  I often do this because I like control over the markup and I want to reduce the divitus in my theme.  It also lets me create layouts that more directly match what I need.  It's pretty easy to create your own panel layouts in your theme.  [Read more here](http://drupal.org/node/495654).

Another option is to override the panel template files in your theme.  Similar to any module that provides a template file, you can copy that template file to your theme and change the markup.  You'll find the panel template files in [path_to_modules]/panels/plugins/layouts/[each_layout].

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [Clean Markup](https://www.drupal.org/project/clean_markup) Module.

> This module aims to clean up, enhance and facilitate the customization
>   of markup for Drupal core and several popular contrib modules such as
>   Panels.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Drupal Answers.